# Crontab to restart jboss server

Tags: cron, jboss

i want to create a crontab to restart my jboss server every night. Nothing special and i thought it would be easy....

I got this crontab:

```
0 22 * * * /home/user/SoftZ/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/jboss_restart.sh
```

So every night at 22h it launches jboss_restart.sh which is as this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo restarting jboss >> /home/user/SoftZ/logz.log

for pjboss in `ps -Af | grep -v grep | grep jboss | grep -v jboss_restart.sh | awk '{ print $2 }'`
do
    kill -9 ${pjboss}
    echo Killing >> /home/user/SoftZ/logz.log
done

echo Starting >> /home/user/SoftZ/logz.log
sh /home/user/SoftZ/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/run.sh -c all &
echo Finish >> /home/user/SoftZ/logz.log
```

So it's basic... the cron starts well and jboss_restart.sh too, everything is logged in logz.log and active process of jboss is killed but run.sh isn't started..... I tried several things such as chmod on the script, change the synthax of the command and crontab,... but nothing works. It's very annoying.

Could you help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `sh /home/user/SoftZ/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/run.sh -c all &` work correctly off the command line ? I always try to put the full path into shell scripts for cron, ie `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Doing kill -9 is very drastic. Are you OK with the potential data loss this might produce?

Comment: the data loss is not a problem, it's on a testing environment.

Comment: i've tried with /bin/sh without success. the script works correctly when I launch it from the console, that's why it's weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `run.sh` script saves logging infomration on console. If you want to run it in background you should:

1. Redirect output to `/dev/null`:

   ```
   run.sh -c all &> /dev/null &
   ```
2. Turn off console logging in the `login-conf.xml`.

But I think the best solution if will be use `jboss_init_redhat.sh` script. You can find it in the `bin` directory (the same where the `run.sh` script is placed).

The `jboss_init_redhat.sh` script is wrapper on `run.sh` which allow you to use it as Init V script - it has such parameters like `start`, `stop`. You have to set up it properly but its quite easy - just open it and edit some bash variables.

You can have some problems when you use some user to connect to JMX console. In that case you have to modify that script and add credential - the JMX use used to stop JBoss instance.

You have to modify `JBOSS_CMD_STOP` variable and add there your credentials.

Comment: the solution with the jboss_init_redhat works. So in my script, because I need to understand, I must set console configuration?

Comment: @HowHigH I am not sure if I understand your question. You want to know if you have to redirect outpu from console to `/dev/null` if you use `jboss_init_redhat.sh`? In that case it is not necessery, by default if you run JBoss using these script all output is redirect to `/dev/null`. If you want to check it you can open script and find  `JBOSS_CONSOLE` variable. In that variable you have definition where to redirect output from JBoss.

Comment: no, with my own script. With jboss_init_redhat.sh all works fine :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really certain about this, but maybe your call to the `run.sh` script gets killed after your cron script finishes, since you are starting it in the background (&). You could try calling it with `nohup` to keep it running even when the cron process finishes, e. g.

```
/usr/bin/nohup /home/user/SoftZ/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/run.sh -c all &
```

This also works when you want to run a process on a remote machine but log out after starting it. Maybe give it a try.

Comment: it doesn't work. thanks for your attention